# click checbox in a browser pop up using python

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox, popup

Need a help regarding a selenium based pop up.
After I authenticate to a URL, I get a pop up with a checkbox and Open/Cancel buttons. Am trying to click a checkbox on a selenium pop up (looks like a javascript or so ?), and then an Open button.
[image: image attached]

I tried browser.switch_to.alert() and a few other things, but failed to handle.

```
browser.switch_to.alert()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\saleh\PycharmProjects\LearnPythonSaleh\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 55, in alert
    alert.text
  File "C:\Users\saleh\PycharmProjects\LearnPythonSaleh\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\alert.py", line 67, in text
    return self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_GET_ALERT_TEXT)["value"]
  File "C:\Users\saleh\PycharmProjects\LearnPythonSaleh\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\saleh\PycharmProjects\LearnPythonSaleh\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)
```

Currently, I handle it using pyautogui as below (but this will need browser to be in focus. looking for a reliable way to handle this)

```
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.press("tab")  # Press the tab key once to go to the check 
box in the browser pop up
pyautogui.press('enter')  # Press the ENTER key to tick he check box 
in the browser pop up
pyautogui.press("tab")  # Press the tab key once to go to the 'Open 
button
pyautogui.press('enter')  # Press the ENTER key to Click on the 'Open 
button
```

Appreciate any help on this... thanks

Comment: that's Chrome's prompt so is outside the DOM.  You might try to find a preference you can set in Chromedriver's options.  https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find the exact preference to use. Can you please guide me through further?

Comment: You'll need to hack it out.  Check your browser's preference file before/after making that change in the browser.  In Chrome: chrome://settings/content/fileHandlers  (You may not be able to set certain preferences in Chrome options, though...)  Might be easier to just set a profile with the setting already saved.